# Searching data for habits

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, uses-of-open-data

I am searching for open datasets which has tags of habits.

A habit could be : eating, drinking, everyday activities, anything.
The type of data could be text, no images are required.

This dataset will be used for machine learning.

Can anyone give any input?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you ... http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/?sort=modified&refine.language=en

Comment: Welcome to OpenData SE! Could you please explain in your answer how this link can be used to find datasets containing tags of habits?

Comment: How are these 'habits' different from 'verbs'?